# Visual C++ does not autocomplete the class members

Tags: c++, autocomplete

EDIT: I am using VS 2008 Express Edition

Not sure why, but sometimes I can't get Visual C++ to autofill the class members.

i.e. if I have a class "Letters" with members a, b, c, d

and I have an instance letter,

When I type

```
Letters letter
letter.  // say, I want letter.a
```

(When I type letter., I would get a list of members, i.e. a,b,c,d to choose from).

But sometimes I don't. The project builds fine..So I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: You likely have to wait until IntelliSense updates the database.

Comment: @sharptooth, I've closed the project and reopened it, and still nothing. Is there a way to force update  the IntelliSense db?

Comment: Usually you just have to save all changes and wait. It takes some time. Yes, it's not very convenient.

Comment: As there have been changes in IntelliSence recently, you'll have to give us your VS version, with precision if you installed service packs.

Comment: 2008 Express Edition. No service packs have been added.

Answer (score 4):

It can often be fixed by closing the Solution, deleting the .ncb file, and opening the solution again. This way the database is rebuilt from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

ctrl+space can sometimes encourage it along.

Comment: This is a good tip, however the (other) problem I am having is that not *everything* shows up. So I think the problem is, just like others pointed out, with updating the Intellisense DB.